# Log file was not created

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, log4net

I need to generate log file in my local Folder.
I use the Following Code for generate Log File in Console Application.But the LogFile was not created.Is any Changes Are need?

I use the the Following Codes in App.Config File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>    
<configuration>    
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>

  <!-- <log4net configSource="log4net.config" /> -->
  <log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="Log4NetApplicationLog.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender" >
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="Header" value="[Header]\r\n" />
        <param name="Footer" value="[Footer]\r\n" />
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="Log4NetApplicationRollingLog.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="KeyOne" value="ValueOne"/>
  </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

I use the Following File for **Class File**

```
 class Program
    {
        private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlConfigurator.Configure(); //only once

            Log.Debug("Application is starting");
            Console.WriteLine("Test Line");
            var testClass = new TestClass();
            testClass.LogSomething();

            Log.Debug("Application is ending");
            Console.Read();
        }
        public class TestClass
        {

            private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

            public void LogSomething()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                {
                    Log.InfoFormat("CurrentTime is [{0}]", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd-hh.mm.ss~fff"));
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is `ConsoleAppender` working correctly? Does it output?

Comment: No @YeldarKurmangaliyev

Comment: Then it means that it is not "file is not created" but "log4net" is not being configured.

Answer (score 2):

I keep this bookmark handy and refer back to it when I can't get my logging to work - it usually ends up being a configuration issue...

http://haacked.com/archive/2006/09/27/Log4Net_Troubleshooting.aspx/

Basically, you add this to your appSettings

```
<add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
```

...then you add the following before your `</configuration>`

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true">
    <listeners>
      <add 
        name="textWriterTraceListener" 
        type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
        initializeData="C:\temp\log4net.txt" />
    </listeners>
  </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Run your application, then go to C:\temp\log4net.txt and see if log4net is throwing any errors. That'll usually help pinpoint the cause of the problem.